# Wordpress filter from variable?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, add-filter

I can't remember how to structure this correctly, but I'm trying to change the output of a `get_option` setting within a Wordpress site. I can get the variable output correctly, but I can't remember what I need to do to get it to filter the output and updated within the `apply_filters` function.

This is what I got so far:

```
$tab_pos = get_option('tab-items');
add_filter($tab_pos['position'], 'tab_filter');
function new_tab_pos(){
    return 'right';
}
apply_filters('tab_filter', 'new_tab_pos');
```

Basically the `$tab_pos['position']` is returning `left` and I want to change it to `right` but I can't remember to to get it to hook into that to make the update. I'm also not sure if I need to updated it with a `str_replace` or something of that sort.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to change the `get_option('tab-items')` value to return right instead of left?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your parameters and function usage the wrong way around... I think you want something along these lines:

```
<?php
$tab_pos = get_option('tab-items');
$tab_pos['position'] = apply_filters('tab_filter', $tab_pos['position']);
function new_tab_pos($position){
    return 'right';
}
add_filter('tab_filter', 'new_tab_pos', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but doesn't see to be effecting anything. I know that the `tab-items` comes back with some sort of an array of data and I'm trying to target the postion within there which is why I had the `$tab_pos['position']` so I can get the default value of `left` and then change it to `right`

Comment: I've edited, but again this is untested. The main point I was trying to make with this answer though, was you had the usage of add_filter and apply_filters backwards. And the parameters incorrect for them also.